# Erro na chave estrangeira em SQL

Tags: banco-de-dados

O erro está nas duas ultimas linhas. Considerando que código é chave primaria de cidade e sigla é chave primária de setor.

```
CREATE TABLE funcionario(
    codigo int NOT NULL,
    nome varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    sexo char,
    estcivil varchar(10),
    rg int(11),
    cpf int(11) NOT NULL,
    datanasc date,
    naturalidade varchar(15),
    dataadm date,
    endereco varchar(30),
    complemento varchar(10),
    bairro varchar(15),
    cidade varchar(15),
    cep int (11),
    fone int (11),
    celular int (11),
    funcao varchar(15),
    setor varchar(3),
    salario decimal(10,2),
    CONSTRAINT pk_funcionario PRIMARY key(codigo),
    CONSTRAINT fk_cidade FOREIGN key(cidade) REFERENCES cidade(codigo)
);
```

Comment: Qual o erro apresentado?

Comment: chave duplicada

Comment: Edita tua pergunta e adiciona o erro e o código dele.